# android status bar font color is always white

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, material-components-android, android-statusbar

I have the following theme for light mode in themes.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryVariant1Light</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryVariant1Light</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

I definite night theme values in night/themes.xml as follows:

```
 <style name="Theme.MainTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryVariant1Dark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryVariant1Dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
 </style>
```

The colors are white and black for `colorPrimaryVariant1Light` and `colorPrimaryVariant1Dark` respectively.

The background color of the status bar changes nicely, but the color of text and icons in the status bar remains white in both modes, so in light mode it is invisible on white background.
How can this color be modified to be for example black in light mode?
My minSdkVersion is 23 and I don't do any changes of translucency.

Answer (score 0):

Use this set system status bar fond color dark

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth);
    setSystemBarDark(this);
}
```

```java
public static void setSystemBarDark(Activity act) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        View view = act.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to do the change in xml? Why would I need a version check if my minimum is 23? Why does my solution does not work? What view do I set the UI Visibility if I need the change to apply across the whole app?

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` is deprecated